# How do I run an action for all requests in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have some code I want to run for every request that comes into Flask-- specifically adding some analytics information. I know I could do this with a decorator, but I'd rather not waste the extra lines of code for each of my views. Is there a way to just write this code in a catch all that will be applied before or after each view?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Flask has dedicated hooks called before and after requests:

- [`Flask.before_request()`](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.before_request)
- [`Flask.after_request()`](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.after_request)

Both are decorators:

```
@app.before_request
def do_something_whenever_a_request_comes_in():
    # request is available

@app.after_request
def do_something_whenever_a_request_has_been_handled(response):
    # we have a response to manipulate, always return one
    return response
```